# Induction: Negation for Even Integers implies Negation for all Integers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

*I have a little confusion  regarding inductive method.*

**Notation and Definition:** Given, $n!=2^{n- s_2(n)}\times a \times r$ ($a, r$ are odd numbers), here,  $s_{2}(n) $ is the number of $1$'s in the binary representation of $n$. We use logarithm of  base $2$ and ignore any positive number less than $1$.

**Context:**
By induction I would like to show -

$  \log(a)-\log(r)=n- s_2(n)-2, \forall n\geq 7  $.

The basis step would be for $n=7$. In  inductive step, we assume that-
  $  \log(a)-\log(r)=n- s_2(n)-2, \forall n\geq 7  $ is true, this is  the inductive hypothesis

Now, we need to show that,   $  \log(a_1)-\log(r_1)=(n+1)- s_2(n+1)-2$ is also true.
where $(n+1)!=2^{(n+1)- s_2(n+1)}\times a_1 \times r_1$ ($a_1, r_1$ are odd numbers).

If I am not wrong it can be shown that if $n$ is even then  $  \log(a_1)-\log(r_1) \neq (n+1)- s_2(n+1)-2$.

**Question:** Since the proposition is false if $n$ is even, and $n, (n+1)$  can not be *odd number at the same time*, does it  imply that-

$  \log(a)-\log(r)\neq n- s_2(n)-2, \forall n > 7  $.

If not,  why above implication is false?  please, write your explanation, thanks.

Comment: Your statement of induction hypothesis is wrong. It should either be (if you are using **Weak Induction**) $\log(a)−log(r)=n−s_2(n)−2$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ or  (if you are using **Strong Induction**) $\log(a)−\log(r)=n−s_2(n)−2$ for all natural numbers $\{7,8,\ldots,n-1\}$ and for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: That the satement $"\log(a)-\log(r)=n- s_2(n)-2, \forall n\geq 7"$ can't hold can also be seen as follows: The RHS is constant, but the LHS can varry by moving factors between $a$ and $r$: Let's given a tripple $a,r, n$ s.t. $n!=2^{n-s_2(n)}ar$ and suppose $a=a'b$ with $b > 1$. Take $r'=br$. Then $n!=2^{n-s_2(n)}a'r'$, but $\log(a') - log(r') = \log(a) -\log(r) - 2\log(b) \neq \log(a) - \log(r).$

Comment: @tj_ , hi, thanks for your response, but I have used this argument , I have been told that its a flimsy argument.

Comment: Hmm, ok. Were you given an explanation why it's flimsy ?

Comment: Of course, you must be careful with the "for all" qantifier: The argument only shows: "there are" $a,r, n$ such that $\log(a)−log(r)\neq n−s_2(n)−2$. But this doesn't tell anything about the stronger statement $"\log(a)−log(r)\neq n−s_2(n)−2, \forall n> 7$".

Comment: @tj_ , also, $a, r$ are coprimes. Note, by hypothesis, there exists $a, r$ such that,   $  \log(a)-\log(r)=n- s_2(n)-2, \forall n\geq 7  $. and yes,  my target is to show the inequality.

Comment: Coprimeness doesn't matter here, because one can take $b$ a prime power, for instance $8! = 2^7 \cdot (3^2\cdot 5) \cdot 7 = 2^7 \cdot 3^2 \cdot (5 \cdot 7)$.

Comment: @tj_ , yap, hail Log! but I was told argument like "The RHS is constant, but the LHS can varry by moving factors=terms (? I hope) " is "flimsy" almost similar context.

Comment: I think I understand: If the statement is: $"$For all $n> 7$ there are (coprime) $r,a$ such that $n! = 2^{n-s_2(n)}ar$ and $\log(a)−log(r) = n−s_2(n)−2"$ than the argument with moving the factors doesn't disprove the statement. What's the quantification for the inequality you want to show: Should $\log(a)−\log(r) \neq n−s_2(n)−2$ hold for all $n>7$ and all $a,r$ ?

Comment: Proof of the inequality: Set $s = n-s_2(n)$. Assume $\log(a)-\log(r)=s-2$. Exponenting with base 2 and using $n!=2^sar$, one finds $n! = 4a^2$ and hence $\nu_2(n!)=2$ (since $a$ odd). Hence $n < 4$. But $n!$ isn't divisible by 4 for $n < 4$. Thus the assumption is wrong. So: $\log(a)-\log(r)\neq s-2$ for all $n$ and all odd $a,r$ with $n!=2^sar$.